# HTMLAgility Pack - OuterHtml Read-only?

Tags: html-agility-pack

Hey there, I am traversing all the links in my own code base, and changing them from `<a href="x">` to `<asp:HyperLink>`'s for localization reasons. I'm using the HTMLAgilityPack for this (and other things) and I'd like to just change the OuterHtml object for the links I find..but it's read-only?

I'm new to the HAP, do I need to create a new node and delete the old one? Has anyone run into this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using...

```
node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(HrefToAspLinkText(node.OuterHtml)), node)
```

hmm. worked, but ugly.

Comment: This has been bugging me for a long time, the help and tooltips for OuterHtml say you can set it, but you can't. This (slightly ugly) way works- thank you!

Comment: Check my comment for a 'better' solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why use the HTML Agility Pack if you're treating the whole document as a string. Instead look up  tags and replace those then write back the document.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourString); // or doc.Load(yourStream);

var links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
foreach (var link in links)
{
    link.Parent.Replace(ConvertLink(link), link);
}
string newDocument = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml; // Or doc.Save();
```

And your `ConvertLink` would look like this:

```
public HtmlNode ConvertLink(HtmlNode aTag)
{
    var link = HtmlNode.Create("asp:HyperLink");
    link.Attributes.Add(...);
    return link;
}
```

(not compiled, so might need some tweaking).